# How to evade Angular HTML sanitizer for XSS

Tags: xss, angularjs

I'm trying to evade the HTML sanitizer in a field I found more vulnerable in my application to test some XSS injection.

The field that I'm trying to exploit is a dropdown with the following code. The vulnerable field is this classNameId, which consists of a "class name - class id" from the database.

```
                <input [(ngModel)]="selectedClassName" [typeahead]="classList" typeaheadOptionField="classNameId"
                class="form-control" [typeaheadMinLength]="0"
                (typeaheadOnSelect)="selectedClass=$event.item.classId;loadApplicationList($event)"
                (focus)="auxName=selectedClassName;selectedClassName=''"
                (blur)="selectedClassName=selectedClassName || auxName">
```

Some tags like b, img and a works in this field, but it filters out attributes like "onerror" and many others.

I was able to insert the script tag in there with a XSS I made, but it doesn't run as Angular treats this as a text. How can I create an XSS that can evade this HTML sanitizer?

The XSS that I made:

```
<<script></script>/span><<script></script>script>alert(1)<<script></script>/script>
```

And this is the result that I got:

[image: XSS applied to the field]

Here's another example of how it looks if I add a b tag in the beginning of the XSS

[image: XSS applied with b tag]

Comment: This is a pure programming question. I suggest to move it SO.

Comment: @mentallurg not it's not. I'm looking into creating a XSS to inject into this field, not fix it.

Comment: Looks like its being set at the text property and not innerHTML in the DOM which wouldn't be exploitable, does the bold tags render?

Comment: @wireghoul yes they do